# Expand QR Code in Adobe Experience Manager

Tags: adobe, aem, adobe-indesign

I am a newbie to adobe Experience Manager (AEM)V6.2 and we are implementing QR code. I am able to generate QR code using the option Menu--> Insert --> Barcodes --> QR Code.

I need the QR code generated at the specific size(1.75in) but the generated QR code doesn't expand with mouse drag on the layout. 
I had attached the image from the designer tool. I just want to get rid of some white space around QR code and expand it to the frame.

From some google references,  i tried to modify the xml source in the below line

```
      field name="QR_CODE_DATA" y="107.4mm" x="148.65mm" w="63.5mm" 
      h="63.5mm" access="readOnly">


     barcode type="QRCode" dataLength="50" moduleWidth="0.0167in" 
     moduleHeight="0.0167in"
```

On any change in moduleWidth and moduleHeight, QR getting messed up

Can anyone help on how the size of the  code can be modified? Thanks in advance.
[image]QR

Comment: Is there any documentation for the UI you are using for barcodes? I don't believe AEM 6.2 generates barcodes by default, but I could be wrong.

Comment: Sure they have a documentation and for creating one, i haven't followed any. AEM 6.2 has an option to embed the data in QR code or bar code

Comment: Found a solution to modify the size from the xml source, but not the complete QR code disappears from my PDF. Is it something like changing the original size affects the visibility?

Comment: Can you please post a link to said documentation? We cant help you if we cant replicate your setup.

Comment: Haven't found the documentation yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured it out. There is a ratio between the outer frame and QR code which must be maintained. If not, the Designer tool preview may show us the output but not in the real time.